# Flask-SQLAlchemy binding another db not working

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to bind another database (within the same server) to my Flask app. I declared the bind key on the table and used SQLALCHEMY_BINDS in my config but I am still getting the error that the table does not exist in the wrong database. Here is my code:

```
class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://user_name:password@server/serology'
    SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {'ccr': 'mysql+pymysql://user_name:password@server/ccr'}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class sample(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'ccr'
    __tablename__ = "sample"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
```

I am getting the error of:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table 'serology.sample' doesn't exist")
```

I can't see why this is not looking for the table in the database that I bound and declared the bind key for. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you check the `sample.query.session` or `sample.query.bind` and verify what db is it using?

Comment: Its using the wrong db and I'm not sure why as I assigned the correct one when binding it. It is looking in serology not ccr

Comment: @Chelsea did you sort this out, and if so what was the issue? I'm seeing the exact same issue, in this case seemingly due to a Python 3.7->3.11 upgrade (plus relevant libraries)

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was occurring when I shared the same DB session between regular App connections using `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` and other DB activity using `SQLALCHEMY_BINDS`.

It is important to keep these separate, since the `__bind_key__` will have been determined on first instantiation of the session.

In my code, I use (and import) the following as convenient per-request session factory:

```
db_sess = flask_scoped_session(session_factory, app)
```

For non-primary tables, I needed to construct a separate DB session:

```
# as part of App initialisation
db = SQLAlchemy()

# in the relevant code block
db.session.query(Non_Primary_DB_Table).filter(...)
```